# Eclipse SWT showing an upside down shell on design page on MacOs X High Sierra

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, shell, swt

I have a problem using the SWT Design page on Eclipse on MacOs X.
It is showing me an upside down image of my shell.
[image: SWT Design Page Upside Down]

If I open my project on BootCamp ( Windows 7 ) the design page is behaving normally and showing me the correct image.

Im using the `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64-4.3.jar`.

On Windows 7: `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.3.jar`.

I'm guessing that mac somehow messes with the graphic driver.

Is anyone having the same problem or having a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is WindowBuilder you are using this looks like Eclipse bugs [526091](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526091) and [525425](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525425).

Unfortunately there is no fix for this yet.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. At least I now know that i'm not the only one with this problem.

Comment: Looks like some fix was put in place but don't think it is merged with Oxygen.2 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526091